# Open other tab from sub-navbar without loading entire new HTML page

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working on a page in a Node Web app with a subnav that looks like this:

[image]

Here's the vanilla HTML for it:

```
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Comments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Is there a way for me to create live links (e.g. Comments) on those tabs without having to render a whole separate route and EJS template?  To me, a process like that would be more efficient and DRY than creating separate templates for each link in the subnav.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!